# Error shown a problem internal to gdb has been detected when doing xv6

Tags: operating-system, gdb, riscv, xv6

I am currently self-studying the course 6.1810 offered by MIT. 'The program is not being run' is shown after I type continue using gdb when doing lab 2.

```
(gdb) file kernel/kernel
Reading symbols from kernel/kernel...
(gdb) b syscall
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80001fe2: file kernel/syscall.c, line 133.
(gdb) c
The program is not being run.
(gdb) c
The program is not being run.
```

Then, I try to run the program but error shown like below.

```
/build/gdb-ZgDh0V/gdb-12.1/gdb/i387-tdep.c:596: internal-error: i387_supply_fxsave: Assertion `tdep->st0_regnum >= I386_ST0_REGNUM' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
----- Backtrace -----
0x55ba4e20a197 ???
0x55ba4e609464 ???
0x55ba4e6096a0 ???
0x55ba4e96dc64 ???
0x55ba4e361b48 ???
0x55ba4e18e6c5 ???
0x55ba4e186800 ???
0x55ba4e5beea0 ???
0x55ba4e4c37d9 ???
0x55ba4e4c3821 ???
0x55ba4e4c752c ???
0x55ba4e4c5868 ???
0x55ba4e3b0de5 ???
0x55ba4e3b4d62 ???
0x55ba4e5c1ebf ???
0x55ba4e424ea9 ???
0x55ba4e3270fa ???
0x55ba4e36ac8d ???
0x55ba4e3b2a7c ???
0x55ba4e37145e ???
0x55ba4e23f774 ???
0x55ba4e5cfd94 ???
0x55ba4e30d6e4 ???
0x55ba4e30da83 ???
0x55ba4e30e206 ???
0x7f36e7e9ce0d ???
0x55ba4e30c7d5 ???
0x55ba4e30e0b4 ???
0x55ba4e30c3cb ???
0x55ba4e96e395 ???
0x55ba4e96e82a ???
0x55ba4e3d871c ???
0x55ba4e3da404 ???
0x55ba4e1340ef ???
0x7f36e6e17d8f __libc_start_call_main
        ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
0x7f36e6e17e3f __libc_start_main_impl
        ../csu/libc-start.c:392
0x55ba4e139e24 ???
0xffffffffffffffff ???
---------------------
/build/gdb-ZgDh0V/gdb-12.1/gdb/i387-tdep.c:596: internal-error: i387_supply_fxsave: Assertion `tdep->st0_regnum >= I386_ST0_REGNUM' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n)
```

I am using gdb-multiarch command to oepn the gdb.

can anyone help me to solve the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone help me to solve the problem please?

You have triggered a GDB [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27235). You should update that bug with a reproducing test (if you can create one).

You can try an older version of GDB (in case that bug was recently introduced). You can also try to build GDB from current source (in case that bug was recently fixed) -- you may at least get a meaningful GDB crash stack trace.

But other than that, there isn't really anything anyone can do to help you here.

---

P.S. You have tagged your question with RISC-V, but GDB is executing `i387`-target specific code, which should *not* be invoked at all on RISC-V.

Is the kernel you are trying to debug compiled for RISC-V, or for `i386`?

Perhaps `set architecture riscv` would nudge GDB into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you and resolved it this way.

Replace command `gdb-multiarch` with `gdb-multiarch -x ./.gdbinit`.

Specify the gdbinit file used for GDB.

NOTE：After running the `make clean` command, there is only one similar file called `.gdbinit.tmpl-riscv`. The `.gdbinit` file mentioned above appears after running the `make qemu gdb` command.